# R - "cannot coerce class ‘"msm.est"’ to a data.frame"

Tags: r

I'm new to R's object-oriented setup, so go easy :)

I am using the `msm` [library](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/msm/index.html), and specifically the `pmatrix` [function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/msm/versions/1.6.7/topics/pmatrix.msm).  This function is correctly working and prints a matrix when called:

`t = pmatrix.msm(x=fb.msm.tech)`.

```
print(t)

            State 1      State 2   State 3    State 4    State 5
State 1 0.215414273 0.0177223229 0.6120709 0.08127077 0.07352177
State 2 0.033494683 0.6421517256 0.2223060 0.02454739 0.07750024
State 3 0.007500551 0.0001843707 0.7530770 0.15781630 0.08142178
State 4 0.008522211 0.0002170102 0.2993561 0.57798320 0.11392148
State 5 0.000000000 0.0000000000 0.0000000 0.00000000 1.00000000
```

`t` is an object of class `msm.est` but I would like to convert it to `data.frame` (or a matrix).  How would I do this?  This results in an error:

```
> data.frame(t)
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"msm.est"’ to a data.frame
```

Here are some attributes about `t`; let me know if you need more info:

```
> typeof(t)
[1] "double"

> str(t)
Error in unclass(x)[i, j] : subscript out of bounds

> class(t)
[1] "msm.est"

> methods(class=class(t))
[1] [     print
see '?methods' for accessing help and source code

> dput(t)
structure(c(0.215414272798276, 0.0334946826176258, 0.00750055145168075, 
0.00852221143845429, 0, 0.0177223229119804, 0.642151725588598, 
0.00018437071164374, 0.000217010203854516, 0, 0.612070862567051, 
0.222305955350619, 0.753077002693833, 0.299356094968411, 0, 0.0812707673639357, 
0.024547392341985, 0.157816299874524, 0.577983203836297, 0, 0.0735217743587564, 
0.0775002441011723, 0.081421775268318, 0.113921479552984, 1), .Dim = c(5L, 
5L), .Dimnames = list(c("State 1", "State 2", "State 3", "State 4", 
"State 5"), c("State 1", "State 2", "State 3", "State 4", "State 5"
)), class = "msm.est")
```

Comment: @MrFlick - does the update to the question work?  If not, I can provide a link to the actual `t` object itself.

Comment: That did the trick; thank you.  If you want to convert your comment to an Answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `msm.est` object is basically just a matrix with a special class. You can remove that class to get the matrix, and then use `data.frame()` to turn the matrix into a data.frame.

```
data.frame(unclass(t))
```